# Interchangeable and difference

Tags: word-usage, difference, usage

Are these interchangeable? What is the difference in use?

> I will do it ***to the same extent*** as you do.
>
> I will do it ***as much as*** you do.
>
> I will do it ***to an equal degree*** as you.
>
> I will do it ***in the same way*** as you.

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 3 versions mean pretty much the same, but would probably be better expressed as

> I will do the same amount [of it] as you.

In most cases the "of it" is optional. "do" could be replaced with a more specific verb to clarify. For example

> I will **eat** the same amount of it as you.
>
> I will **pay** the same amount as you.
>
> I will **run** the same distance as you.

The 4th version has a different meaning

> I will perform the action the same way you do it.

but says nothing as to how much you will do compared to the other person.